# MonoDevelop.Core.GUI missing?

Tags: c#, git, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to port monodevelop-git to MonoDevelop 2.4 (https://github.com/pnobre/monodevelop-git). So far, I've sorted all the errors out, except this one:

I cannot find the MonoDevelop.Core.GUI assembly. Is it replaced in Mono 2.4, and if yes, which one do I need to use now, and how do I use it?

I'm looking for a replacement for `MessageService`.

Thank you!

Yvan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoDevelop.Core.Gui is part of MonoDevelop.Ide.dll in 2.4+.

However, I would suggest you just try using MonoDevelop master, which has git support built in.